# Unable to seed initial data in sqlite3 with Django and Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

### Update:

I'm researching as well but will keep adding links that I think might help

[Migration and Seeding in Django](https://medium.com/@ardho/migration-and-seeding-in-django-3ae322952111)

[Providing initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/)

---

This is the error that I'm getting and it's because I'm not able to write to my database with the docker command(you will see below). That's my assumption.

---

[image]

---

This is my folder structure.

[image]

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  django:
    build: ./api
    command: ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  node-modules:
```

---

**Dockerfile** (inside **api** folder)

```
FROM python:3.7.6

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# Run migrations and load seed data (using SQLite)
RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations
RUN python3 manage.py migrate
RUN python3 manage.py loaddata portal/fixtures/seed.yaml
RUN python3 manage.py loaddata scheduler/fixtures/seed.yaml

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

---

Have tried most of the possible items I was able to search, would really appreciate if someone could help here.

Comment: The `volumes:` are hiding everything your images build (and, for the frontend container, also telling Docker to use an old version of the `node_modules` tree).  If you delete all of the `volumes:` blocks does it work better?

Comment: yes I did delete the older volumes as well, but it didn't work. It was not initializing and adding the values in the db. Had to manually do it as suggested in the answer and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the commands in your Docker Image CLI

```
# Run migrations and load seed data (using SQLite)
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py loaddata portal/fixtures/seed.yaml
python3 manage.py loaddata scheduler/fixtures/seed.yaml
```

Do it in a sequential manner.